# Rails 2: Saving new HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to save a new HABTM relationship between User and Category.

My User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

My Category model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I have the join table set up correctly. THe problem is, I cannot change anything on the User controller, only on the User view. So, in the User view, there's a collection_select:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :title, 
    { :selected => @user.category_ids }, 
    { :multiple => true, :name => 'user[category_ids][]' } 
-%>
```

I can correclty choose the categories that my User belong to, but when I click submit, every other attribute is saved except the category, which is not updated on the join table.

If I inspect the params, I can see that the category_ids is being passed correctly:

```
"user"=>{"category_ids"=>["2", "4"]
```

But i can't do anything with it on the User controller, since I'm not allowed to mess with the code. Is there someway to automatically update the join table, or I have to manually update it?

PS - I cant mess with the User controller because I'm actually building a plugin for Redmine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

im also a RoR newbie buy how about:

```
<% for category in Category.find(:all) %>
  <%= check_box_tag "user[categories_ids][]", category.id,  @user.categories.include(category) %>
  <%= category.title %>
<% end %>
```

Also, double check if your attr_accessible are all there.